# flex Jboss server problem

Tags: flex3

while doing flex project iam unable to start my Jboss server.
can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your ports are already in use (e.g. 1091).

Comment: ports means ? iam not getting you. can you please tell  me what I have to do?

Comment: JBoss runs services on certain ports (port = TCP/UDP port). If those ports are already in use, it fails to start.

Comment: actually in eclipse, in servers view it is not showing Jboss server.and start button also not enabled

Comment: Then I guess you have to create a server configuration.